# antlr lexer rule that may match almost anything

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I got a problem here that I'm sure it is about how antlr works and I am doing it all wrong but I read a lot of docs and tutorials and I still don't fully understand it.

My symptom is thy my grammar stop working when I add (because I need) a lexer rule that may match things it should not. It should only be applied in the right context.

**I need `ATTR` rule because I need `description` and other rules that will follow to get a string from that keyword to end of line.**

This is the conflicting rule:

```
ATTR  
    :   (~('\r'| '\n'))*
    ;
```

It seems it matches anything so it 'eats' the text that should match different tokens. It makes sense, but I need it or I need another solution.

This is my current example **input**:

```
; This is a comment
; Comment 2

audit-template this is the id {
    description a description may include any char but {line break}
}
```

For reference this is my current complete grammar:

```
grammar Grammar;

options { 
  superClass = AbstractTParser;
}

@header {
package antlrTest;

}

@lexer::header {
package antlrTest;
}

@lexer::members {
    private void debug(String str) {
        System.err.println("DEBUG(L) " + str);
    }
}

@members {
    private void debug(String str) {
        System.err.println("DEBUG(P) " + str);
    }
}

parse
  :  (template|'**TODO**') EOF { debug ("EOF"); }
  ;

template : 'audit-template' id=IDENTIFIER OB content=templateContent CB { debug("template id=" + $id.text); }
  ;


templateContent:
    description?
;

description : 'description' ATTR
;

//

COMMENT
  :  ';' ~( '\r' | '\n' )* {$channel=HIDDEN; debug("COMMENT");}
  ;

SPACES : ( '\t' | '\f' | ' ' | '\n'| '\r' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;

OB :    '{' { debug("OB"); }
    ;

CB :    '}' ('\r'| '\n')+ { debug("CB(lf)"); }
        | '}' EOF { debug("CB(eof)"); }
    ;

IDENTIFIER  
    :   ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' )
        ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9' | '.' | ' ' | '\t')*
    ;

ATTR  
    :   (~('\r'| '\n'))*
    ;
```

I am getting this error (the error handling is a bit tweaked):

```
Line 4 char 0
    at antlrTest.AbstractTParser.reportError(AbstractTParser.java:45)
    at antlrTest.GrammarParser.parse(GrammarParser.java:106)
    at antlrTest.TemplateParser.parseInput(TemplateParser.java:15)
    at antlrTest.Main.testFile(Main.java:32)
    at antlrTest.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: NoViableAltException(7@[])
    at antlrTest.GrammarParser.parse(GrammarParser.java:71)
    ... 3 more
```

Solution? Alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: I just got another related doubt. If `IDENTIFIER` rule might match `audit-template this is the id` why didn't I have the same problem?

Comment: An alternative may be use this lexer rule and get the text later in java: `DESCRIPTION : 'description' (~('\r'| '\n'))*`. Is it a good idea?

Comment: make that + not * and see what happens.

Comment: You are right @TheANTLRGuy. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: I am finally quoting all the strings. It is much easier to work with ANTLR and grammars in general that way. That way the lexer knows where the string starts and ends without a context.